# Linq to Entities SqlFunctions.DateDiff not supported

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following code

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

var allItemsOver64 = _inventoryContext.Items.Where(i => 
   (SqlFunctions.DateDiff("dd", i.PrimaryInsured.DoB, now) / 365.0) >= 65);

IQueryable<Item> items65To69 = allItemsOver64.Where(i =>
   (SqlFunctions.DateDiff("dd", i.PrimaryInsured.DoB, now) / 365.0) >= 65 &&
   (SqlFunctions.DateDiff("dd", i.PrimaryInsured.DoB, now) / 365.0) <= 69);
```

But when I try and use allItemsOver64 thus Items65To69.Count() I get this error

> The expression 
>   ((((Convert(DateDiff("dd", [10007].PrimaryInsured.DoB, 26/04/2012 15:03:09)) / 365) >= 65)
>   And 
>   ((Convert(DateDiff("dd", [10007].PrimaryInsured.DoB, 26/04/2012 15:03:09)) / 365) >= 65)) 
>   And 
>   ((Convert(DateDiff("dd", [10007].PrimaryInsured.DoB, 26/04/2012 15:03:09)) / 365) <= 69)) 
>   is not supported.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which RDBMS system are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you could try using [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) rather than SqlFunctions.

Comment: Now I get The expression (((DiffYears([10007].PrimaryInsured.DoB, 26/04/2012 15:25:49) >= 65) And (DiffYears([10007].PrimaryInsured.DoB, 26/04/2012 15:25:49) >= 65)) And (DiffYears([10007].PrimaryInsured.DoB, 26/04/2012 15:25:49) <= 69)) is not supported.

Comment: Nowadays DbFunctions; EntityFunctions is obsolete

Comment: @ThomasHagström - Why would you say that it's obsolete? If you check the documentation, you can see that it's still included in the framework and there are definitely still operations supported there that aren't supported elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I understand the original question related to EF 4.1 but just to note EntityFunctions is now obsolete in EF6 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.objects.entityfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx), so DbFunctions should be used instead if targeting EF6 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

DateDiff function with linq to Entity is following bellow

If you want to

```
Day difference 
EntityFunctions.DiffDays(startDate , endDate);

Hours diff ->
EntityFunctions.DiffHours(startDate , endDate);

Minuutes diff ->
EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(startDate , endDate);
```