# The specified type member 'Offset' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq

I got the exception when the next code run:

```
 var fbPost = db.FacebookStatusUpdates
         .Where(f => 
               f.FacebookUpdateTime - f.ClientTime.Offset <= 
               DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime - ConvertTimeSpan(f.Offset) &&
               f.Status == FacebookNotificationStatus.Active &&
               f.Alarm.User.FbStatus == true).ToList();
```

Exception message

> The specified type member 'Offset' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only 
>   initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are
>   supported.

My model:

```
 public class FacebookStatusUpdate
 {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime FacebookUpdateTime { get; set; }
    public string PostId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FacebookPostTime { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ClientTime { get; set; }
    public int Offset { get; set; }

    public virtual FacebookNotificationStatus Status { get; set; }
    public virtual Alarm Alarm { get; set; }
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: ConvertTimeSpan(f.Offset)  return TimeSpan object.  f.Offset - time in seconds.   ConvertTimeSpan  convert seconds to TimeSpan

Comment: you use `f.ClientTime.Offset` and `f.Offset`. Is that correct?

Comment: DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime.AddSeconds(-f.Offset)   I will try it right now.

Comment: Which type of LINQ API is this? `DbContext`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use LINQ to Entities you need to remember your query will be translated into TSQL - if `Offset` is a custom type then EF has no idea on how to translate it to SQL.

You can of course make this work if you can convert your query to LINQ to Objects i.e.

```
 var fbPost = db.FacebookStatusUpdates
     .Where(f => f.Status == FacebookNotificationStatus.Active &&
                 f.Alarm.User.FbStatus == true)
     .AsEnumerable() // convert from L2E to L2O
     .Where(f => f.FacebookUpdateTime - f.ClientTime.Offset <= 
           DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime - ConvertTimeSpan(f.Offset))
     .ToList();
```

After the call to `AsEnumerable()` the rest of your query is LINQ to Objects which understands `Offset`/`ConvertToTimespan` code. Just to clarify, `AsEnumerable()` won't *materialize* your query right way - you still get lazy loading. However, any further querying after `AsEnumerable()` is done client-side, there is no more interaction with the DB.

When using L2E it's best to stick with the supported [primitive types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382832%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Yhanks, the problem is in DateTimeOffset.  Hmm. so what do you think about stored procedure ?

Comment: @Oleh you could use a stored procedure, OR, you could just not use `Offset` in your query. If you need to do some calculation with an offset you could store it as an `int` in a separate column.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this has to do with the fact that you can't use standard C# methods and properties directly in Linq to entities, since the data from `db.FacebookStatusUpdates` might not be loaded initially. To put it another way: That property can't be translated to SQL.

If my understanding is correct, this might provide a solution for you:

```
var fbPost = db.FacebookStatusUpdates
              .ToList() // <-- Forces evaluation/data retrieval!
              .Where(f => 
                   f.FacebookUpdateTime - f.ClientTime.Offset <= 
                   DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime - ConvertTimeSpan(f.Offset) &&
                   f.Status == FacebookNotificationStatus.Active &&
                   f.Alarm.User.FbStatus == true).ToList();
```

This will load the data into a list before attempting to call `ClientTime.Offset`, therefore allowing you to make that call.

**The cost of this however, is that all the data is loaded** before before the `Where()`-filtering is applied. I guess you have to decide whether this is acceptable or not based on your context and other requirements, or if you will have to look for some other better solution.

Comment: .ToList() // <-- Forces evaluation/data retrieval!  .It convert all date in database to List. data base is to large. It is wrong

Comment: @Oleh I see. I guess I was sort of expecting that. You will just have to look for another solution then. Hope this was still helpful in clarifying the problem though.

Answer (score 1):

The following code can replace `a.MyDate.Offset` in a Linq to Entities query:

```
SqlFunctions.DatePart("TZoffset", a.MyDate)
```

Please remember that this work with SqlServer.

Comment: What's the equivalent of DateTimeOffset.LocalDateTime in linq-to-entities?  In other words, everything BUT the TZOffset?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't directly access the `DateTimeOffset.Offset` property (`f.ClientTime.Offset`), just as you can't access a `DateTime.Year` property directly in Linq to entities - it can't directly be translated into a store expression.

I don't know what your `f.FacebookUpdateTime - f.ClientTime.Offset <= 
               DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime - ConvertTimeSpan(f.Offset)` is supposed to do, but you can take a look at the static [`SqlFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx) class for some common date manipulation functions like [`SqlFunctions.DateDiff()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336316/linq-to-entities-sqlfunctions-datediff-not-supported) that you probably can replace that entire expression with.

Also, are you using EF6? Otherwise you'll have to cast your enum to `int`, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your query in two parts.

```
var fbPost_DBQuery = db.FacebookStatusUpdates
     .Where(f => f.Status == FacebookNotificationStatus.Active &&
                 f.Alarm.User.FbStatus == true).ToList();

fbPost_MemoryQuery = fbPost_DBQuery
     .Where(f => f.FacebookUpdateTime - f.ClientTime.Offset <= 
           DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime - ConvertTimeSpan(f.Offset))
     .ToList();
```

fbPost_DBQuery is going to query more information from the database and then filtered in fbPost_MemoryQuery. But it will work.