# Kendo UI for ASP.Net MVC. Grid sorting error with additional entity property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, kendo-ui, grid

I have a sorting problem with kendo ui grid.
I have a Entity class **Port**, in partial class I added additional property:

```
public partial class Port {

    [NotMapped]
    [XmlIgnore]
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

I am using this property in other program parts.
In controller I have:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (!CanViewPorts())
            return new EmptyResult();
        ViewBag.CanEditPorts = CanEditPorts();
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Ports([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        if (!CanViewPorts())
            return new EmptyResult();
        var all = _classificatoryService.GetAllPorts();
        return Json(all.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I'am using method Ports in my view to populate kendo ui grid.
My view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Port>()
      .Name("Ports")
      .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Template(Toolbar().ToString()))
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(c => c.PortId);
          columns.Bound(c => c.Code);
          columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
          columns.Bound(c => c.AlternativeName);
          columns.Bound(c => c.SubDivision);
          columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a class='k-button k-button-icontext' href='" + Url.Action("Details", "Port") + "/#=PortId#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit mr5'></span>Details</a>").Width(110);  //"<#=PortId#>"
          columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a class='newPortBtn k-button k-button-icontext' href='" + Url.Action("NewPort", "Port") + "/?portId=#=PortId#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit mr5'></span>Edit</a>").Visible(canEditPorts).Width(110);
      })
                .Sortable()
                .ColumnMenu()
                .Filterable()
                .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                    .Refresh(true)
                    .PageSizes(true)
                    .ButtonCount(5))
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Model(model => model.Id(x => x.PortId))
                        .Read(read => read.Action("Ports", "Port"))
                    .Sort(sort => sort.Add(x => x.ChartererId).Descending())
                        .Create(c => c.Action("NewPort", "Port"))

                ))
```

As you can see I'a not using additional property **Countryname** in this view.

Ok, grid gets ports and show it properly.
Then I'am trying to sort and click column header.

First click (ASC) - Ok, grid sorted by this column in ascending order.

Second click (DESC) - Ok, grid sorted by this column in descending order.

Third click (unsort) - Grid must be unsorted, but I have 500 (Internal Server Error).

In chrome/Network/Preview I have:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The specified type member 'CountryName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers,
>   entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: There are many other examples of this question on SO that have been answered. [[1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997792/the-specified-type-member-offset-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities)] [[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584660/the-specified-type-member-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities-only-initializer)] [[3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867470/the-specified-type-member-userscount-is-not-supported-in-linq-to-entities)]